# Android Lollipop Webview rendering issue

Tags: android, webview

WebView was working fine in Kitkat but when I upgrade Moto G mobile to Lollipop webview is not working properly. It shows only few lines from HTML file but till Kitkat it shows all the content properly.

It shows error like this "This page contains the following errors: error on .......... Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: the rendering is missing

Comment: Use remote WebView debugging: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging